# Raspberry Pi 3 isn't finding WiFi Networks

Tags: wifi, connection, internet

I'm used to using RP2 with the WiFi dongles and I just picked up my RP3 which should work with the built in WiFi.

However, upon running `startx` and trying to configure the WiFi, it merely states:

> No wireless interfaces found.

I'm trying to connect to my school's WiFi, so naturally I do not have any control over router settings. So I'm wondering if there is a telltale way to at least get it to see the networks? It looks like this is a common problem, but most solution involve tweaking router settings which I do not have the liberty to do.

Comment: I had teething problems with the Pi 3 not recognising (European) WiFi channels, which prevented the onboard adapter from seeing my router. Some suggestions [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43474/how-to-enable-wi-fi-channel-12-on-raspberry-pi-3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try executing the following through the command prompt:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
```

***wait for reboot***

```
sudo branch=next rpi-update
sudo reboot
```

***wait for reboot***

This should grab the latest firmware and updates to make your Pi be able to successfully find networks and connect to them.

I might also suggest getting `wicd`. This is a Wireless and Wired connection manager. You can get this GUI program by executing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Comment: What is the purpose in running `rpi-upgrade` after running `spt-get update` `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` ? My understanding was that `rpi-update` wasn't necessary if you run those three commands.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen, I'm assuming you meant `rpi-update`, because there is no `rpi-upgrade`. You should upgrade packages first, because it might be an issue with a driver, or even an out-of-date rpi-update package. Then that you've guaranteed rpi-update is recent, you update the firmware to rule-out any issues with out-of-date Pi firmware.