# RPI 3 doesn't see my wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I've tried fresh installs of Debian, Debian Lite and Ubuntu Mate, but my wifi doesn't show up.

In Debian Lite I followed this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

In Ubuntu Mate I tried plugin in an ethernet cable to upgrade everything possible, but it didn't help.

I can see lots of other wifi networks, but mine is not showing up.

This is my wifi info, seen from OSX. It is not a hidden network.

[image]

Comment: Do you see your wlan if you run `iwlist scan` in a terminal?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install crda` enabled 12, 13

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44253/29103).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bug in current software/firmware which prevents the on-board WiFi from running on Channel 12.

Channel 12 & 13 are not available in all countries. There is a WiFi Country setting in `raspi-config` but unfortunately it does not work with the current firmware.

Some users have reported success, but this may be related to those using the latest pre-release firmware.

EDIT
Even after upgrading to 4.4.9 I still had only channels 1-11.

Installing `sudo apt-get install crda` enabled 12, 13

Comment: Very accurate, thanks. Switched to another channel and it worked fine. Do you know where I can track the progress of this bug?

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. Function perfect for me, in Raspberry pi 3 b with Kali.