# Why can't my Raspberry Pi find any WiFi networks?

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

There is a [similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44253/raspberry-pi-3-isnt-finding-wifi-networks) to my question, but the answers were more specific to that situation.

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4b. I do not see any WiFi networks in the GUI WiFi pane, even though my phone can see multiple WiFi networks and my phone is also activating a hotspot.

What is a standard way to investigate why this would be? Assuming my Pi's hardware is not broken, what factors would cause a Pi, or a computer in general, not to see any WiFi networks?

Comment: Have you done the steps in the answer "similar question"?

Comment: What is your Wi-Fi country set to?

Comment: @CoderMike I don't know, how do I check?

Comment: @MatsK I can try them but that situation seems different because they're using Raspberry Pi OS. I think the problem might be on the Ubuntu level actually. So I posted my question to Ask Ubuntu. I am also not able to load webpages even with an Ethernet cable attached. I think there is something really strange in my internet settings. I will try to re-flash the operating system.

Comment: Ok, I had the same issue with "Raspberry Pi OS" and a Raspberry Pi 4, and after updating it via Ethernet the WiFi just started to work magically.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment, you said:

> the problem might be on the Ubuntu level actually. So I posted my question to Ask Ubuntu

I *feel certain* you're correct. While Ubuntu and RPi OS are both Debian derivatives, there are **substantial differences** between the two distributions. In particular, **network management** might be considered *"completely different"* - at least in terms of their default network toolsets :

- Ubuntu relies mostly on [NetworkManager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager) for network configuration and device management.
- RPi OS is more *de-centralized*, using `dhcpcd`, `wpa-supplicant` (for example), and other legacy tools to accomplish the same objectives.

For this reason, your decision to post on `Ask Ubuntu` is a sound choice. I might go so far as to say that all networking questions for users of Ubuntu on the RPi platform should be considered "off-topic". But I've digressed with that opinion - question closures will likely continue to be determined in [*ad hoc*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc) fashion as they are now.