# Raspberry Pi 3 wifi, is it dual band?

Tags: wifi

Does anyone know if the new Pi 3 onboard wifi will work with a 5Ghz access point?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43306/does-pi3-wi-fi-support-5-ghz-and-does-it-need-an-extra-antenna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't, sorry. Build-in RPi3 wifi is for 2.4GHz only